# uibmodalinstance result/reason/close/dismiss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap modals, but without being able to take advantage of their full functionality.

My modal is basically an edit popup. So it has a **Save** and a **Cancel**.

- If it's **Save**d, successfully, it should close and then the parent
  should route to another page.
- If it's **Cancel**ed  it should close but not reroute.

Things I don't really get:

- what/where I capture the 'reason' when it's dismissed
- if I can use this to decide whether to reroute
- how closed/result/dismiss work together.

I've looked at a bunch of answers, and I just don't seem to see how they are handled together.

```
        var modalInstance = $uibModal
        .open({
            templateUrl: 'cartModalContent',
            controller: 'cartModalInstanceController',
            controllerAs: 'cartModalVm',
            resolve: {
                payData: vm.PayData
            }
        })
        .closed
            .then(function(){
                    $state.go('layout.package-labels');
             });
        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            // ??
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt [always go to the docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). Under the Modal section you will find this text

> The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:
>
> close(result) (Type: function) - Can be used to close a modal, passing a result.
>
> dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - Can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason.
>
> result (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed.
>
> opened (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables.
>
> closed (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal is closed and the animation completes.
>
> rendered (Type: promise) - Is resolved when a modal is rendered.

What it means is

1. when you invoke the `$uibModal.open` method (and pass the modal definition object to it) you will get a modal instance
2. you can access several promises from the modal instance. these promises will act according to what you do with the modal.
3. So when you `dismiss` your modal, the `result` promise will reject and when you `close` the modal it will resolve.

So your code need to look something like

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: 'modalCtrl',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  size: size,
  appendTo: parentElem,
  resolve: {
    info: function () {
      return '42';
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (resolvedResponse) {
  $state.go('whereever')
}, function (rejectionResponse) {
  // do something else
});
```

And because your use case is a simple ok/cancel dialog, you can use the built in `close`/`dismiss` expressions like so

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$close('ok')">OK</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')">Cancel</button>
```

and when you close the modal

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (resolvedResponse) {
   // resolvedResponse = 'ok'
}, function (rejectionResponse) {
   // rejectionResponse = 'cancel'
});
```